# How can I replicate the same magic in NSNotificationCenter where it automatically unregisters observers?

Tags: swift, memory-leaks

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange, 
object: context, queue: nil) { notification in /.../ }
```

When you register for NSNotifcation like this, according to the documentation you don't need to unregister

> Discussion If your app targets iOS 9.0 and later or macOS 10.11 and
>   later, you don't need to unregister an observer in its dealloc method.
>   Otherwise, you should call this method or removeObserver: before
>   observer or any object specified in
>   addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock: or
>   addObserver:selector:name:object: is deallocated.

But before iOS 9.0 you would have to unregister like this

```
deinit {
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, 
    name: NSNotification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange, 
    object: nil)
}
```

But how does NSNotificationCenter know to unregister my object when it gets deallocated?

I'm trying to implement a similar kind of logic and I would also like this auto unregister feature. Consider:

```
Class Publisher {
  var callback:()-> Void
  func subscribe( callback:()-> Void)  {
    self.callback = callback
  }
}

Class Subscriber {
  var publisher = Publisher()
  init() {
   publisher.subscribe { /*do something*/ }
  }
  deinit {
     publisher.unsubscribe()  //I want this to happen automatically
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But how does NSNotificationCenter know to unregister my object when it gets deallocated?

The notification center's reference to the target is ARC-weak. So it is automatically nilified when the target goes out of existence. So when the notification center gets ready to post to that target, it looks first to see if it is nil, and if it is, it says "Oh, well, that target is gone," and unregisters the target.

As for your main question, that is exactly how publish-and-subscribe works already with the Combine framework. The subscriber is wrapped in an AnyCancellable and stored, and when it is released it is cancelled and sends a `cancel` message up the pipeline to the publisher.

Comment: No reference of the object is passed in addObserver. You just pass in a block.

Comment: See https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/subscribers/subscribersanycancellable.html for more about AnyCancellable.

Comment: @erotsppa But that is just syntactic sugar. `addObserver` hands you _back_ an observer object. It is the target (and retains the block). When it goes out of existence it is unregistered in the way I just explained.